# How to have Chrome rewriting address bar

Tags: google-chrome

there's an url I open several type per day.

> Something like "http://myarchive.com/id=3"

Is there a way to write in address bar something like

> my #3

and have chrome rewrite and open the complete url

> Something like "http://myarchive.com/id=3"

note: 3 above exposed is dynamic, which means will be 4, 5, or whatever

Comment: Why not just use a bookmark?

Comment: good point, @cdr Forgot to say #3 is dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the guide from http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-custom-search-engines-google-chrome/

You click right on the adress bar, edit search engines. Now, for your search engine have it have a keyword `my` and then your URL `http://myarchive.com/id=%s`

Now, you can type `my`, a space and then your number.

Good luck!